# Grove Pi+ CO2 MH-Z16 sensor

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, grovepi+

I am using a Raspberry Pi 3 B model with a Grove Pi+ (1.2.2 firmware), and Raspbian for Robots Image.
I have plugged in the [CO2 MH-Z16](http://www.winsen-sensor.com/products/ndir-co2-sensor/mh-z16.html) sensor in RPISER port, and I am trying 
to execute the code that is available [in Dexter's Github](https://github.com/DexterInd/GrovePi/blob/master/Software/Python/grove_co2_sensor/grove_co2_example.py)

I am getting the following issues:

First time I tried the code, it was working but it was getting very strange results, always out of range and strange temperatures.
It calls the sensor every 18 second.

Now, when I plugged-in the sensor in de RPISER port (with the rpi on), the raspberry pi get frozen. If I tried to restart it, it is not restarting until the sensor is plugged out the rpi. I do not know what is going on, and how to solve this issue. Sometimes, the rpi does not get frozen but the mouse and the keyboard suddenly stop working. If I try to restart the rpi whith the sensor, the rpi is not restarting, it get stucks.

Can I use this sensor in another port?

Any help or any hint?

Answer (score 0):

Oh yes update your firmware. I also took a long time..
https://www.dexterindustries.com/GrovePi/get-started-with-the-grovepi/updating-firmware/